# svn checkout into parent directory of existing checkouts without moving files

Tags: svn

I have a directory structure like this (for a TYPO3 webpage) on SVN:

```
webroot/
      fileadmin/
              css/
              ts/
      typo3conf/
              ext/
              ...
```

I checked out *fileadmin* and *typo3conf* to the webroot of my server.
Later on I had to add some files to the webroot itself (i.e. not into one of the sub directories from above).

Now if I try to checkout *webroot* to my server, SVN complains about existing subtrees (fileadmin, typo3conf). The `--force` flag doesn't do the trick, neither.

I found some solutions moving subtrees back and forth. But this is no option for me because this is a running server.

Is there another option without having to move the already checked out subtrees?

Comment: What version of svn do you use? Do you have a .svn directory only in your checked out directory or in every subdir, too?

Comment: I have version 1.6.17 - there's a .svn directory in every subdir.

Answer (score 0):

This will only be possible if your svn repository contains the `webroot` directory with the subdirectories `fileadmin` and `typo3conf`.

Otherwise you first have to create such a directory structure. Then one way to achieve what you want is to replace your live `.svn` directories.

For this you could check out a fresh instance of `webroot` and (if you really want your live files untouched) throw away everything but the `.svn` directories.

Then on your live directory `webroot` remove all directories `.svn` and replace them with the ones from your fresh checkout.

After that there is a consistent svn directory structure in your live `webroot` directory and you should be able to svn add files on the top level directory.

Comment: webroot exists in my repository - sorry maybe i was unclear. Removing all .svn subdirs would work, of course. My hope was that there is some proper SVN solution... If I just checkout webroot somewhere else and move only the parent .svn to the server?

Answer (score 0):

If finally found a quite straightforward solution: First I checkout the *webroot* repository with a depth of *"immediates"* to a temporary folder:

```
mkdir tmp
svn co --depth immediates URL/webroot tmp  
A    tmp/typo3conf
A    tmp/fileadmin
A    ....
```

Then I just move the whole parent .svn to the unversioned parent dir:

```
mv -R tmp/.svn webroot/
```

That's it!